# Did someone delete my comment on the Colorado drivers license question?

Tags: discussion

I posted a comment, which was replied to, but I do not see the comment anymore.

Comment: What's the thread ID?

Comment: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6665/do-i-need-a-physical-address-to-get-a-drivers-license

Comment: Yep, deleted 9 hours ago.  Must have gotten flagged.  I just deleted the responding comment.

Comment: Where did you go to see that? I'd like to know who did it and why. The comment was completely on point. Hopefully whoever did it will see this and explain.

Comment: I think only moderators can see deleted comments.  @jimsug did the delete, apparently in response to a "Not Constructive" flag.  Since I know your reputation here I agree the comment was helpful, but in isolation I can see how it could be (and was) taken as an ad hominem attack.  jimsug will probably be up on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24153/the-sidebar) soon if you want to get his view or ask him to undelete.

Comment: Perhaps the comment wasn't helpful, I don't know, but helpful is not the standard for comments. CO has pretty strict drivers license address requirements. The best way around them is to get a letter from a shelter. Getting mail at a friend or family also works. When someone says they want to get around the law but **do not want to** (not **can't**)  involve friends, family, or a shelter, they are shutting down the best avenues. I merely said that a person who will not use those resources it likely the person that CO does not want to license. Which is true. Like prima facie true.

Comment: I agree you are correct about the standards for comments.  I think if you repost that explanation as a comment or an answer it would be good.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it was me.

**I've undeleted it**, but... there wasn't really any context around the comment. *Helpful* may not be the standard for comments, but *constructive* is. What was the user meant to do, based on that comment?

I don't really believe that a user's reputation should have bearing on whether they may post unconstructive comments or not. If a user's reputation was supposed to be a factor in how valuable a comment should be considered, it'd probably be visible at all times on the comment, and not just in the tooltip.

If your comment had been posted as an answer, with the explanation from the comment above, then the threshold for deletion would be much higher.

Comment: Constructive is interesting. If a person asks a question such as, *here are the legal requirements for X, I don't want to meet the requirements, how can I still get X?* I'm sure there are constructive ways to answer that, I was probably just tired.

Comment: @jqning I wouldn't have made assumptions about what the legislature "wanted", without reference to actual legislative debate transcripts or something like that. It's not prima facie true that the legislature doesn't want that "type of person" to get a licence. It's totally possible they just didn't consider this "type of person"'s situation.

Comment: @jqning And what is constructive about telling somebody that "reality is harsh".

Comment: @Dawn Like I said, I'm sure there are constructive ways to answer the question. And mine was a comment not an answer. Do you agree that states don't want a certain class of people getting drivers licenses?

Comment: @jqning Yup, but I don't presume to know whether a particular individual is in one of those classes, nor is it useful speculation from a legal perspective unless attempting to use legislative history in the face of statutory ambiguity. I don't think comments should be used to just say random things that aren't relevant to improving the question or answer. I don't think I'll stick around if "it was a comment, not an answer" can be an excuse to tell people that reality is harsh. http://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: @jqning Maybe the chat room is a better place to have side discussions about the wants of the legislature.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24153/the-sidebar